# Sony A6000 SDK API Issues

Tags: python, sony-camera-api

I have a Sony a6000 and I am missing API commands. I have upgraded firmware (v3.21) and remote control to the newest version (v4.20).

When I try getAvailableApiList I only get back a handful of commands (getMethodTypes, getAvailableApiList, getEvent, startRecMode, stopRecMode). When I try getVersions I can see versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4. If I attempt the getAvailableApiList with any different version I get an error 12. If I attempt to getEvent with a True param it either times out or give me an error 1, 'Unknown'.  I am using python to call the API and am connected to the camera's wifi. Any insight and/or help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I may have some progress. First, I used libsonyapi from Github (https://github.com/petabite/libsonyapi). This allowed me more functionality through the Sony Rest API. Second, I didn't fully read the compatibility chart to realize the a6000 series does not support file transfer through the API. Thirdly, on these cameras the startRecMode must be used before accessing more API functionality. I am now attempting this on the a7ii and hoping my file transfer woes will be over.

Thank you,
Matt